# Collection of all ordered pairs with fixed first coordinate is a proper class

Tags: set-theory, axioms

Let $a$ be a fixed set. Set $A = \{(a,B) : B = B\}$. How do I show that the class $A$ is proper? I think it should be since it is basically the same as the class of all sets. I was considering using the axiom of replacement with a function which sends $(x, y) \to y$ but how do I write this function out as a definite condition? And where do I send everything that isn't an ordered pair?

Comment: Can't you have the function have domain $A$, so every input is a pair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write down a formula $\varphi(x,y)$ saying "$x$ is a pair of the form $(a,y)$". This $\varphi$ serves as the function you want to apply replacement to.

Note that the property $\varphi$ you define needs only be functional on the set $A$, so you don't have to send non-pairs anywhere.

Comment: What do you mean it needs to only be functional on $A$? In our definition it needed to be a function from the class of all sets to the class of all sets

Comment: I think the more common definition of replacement requires the relation $\varphi$ to be functional only on a chosen set, and then replacement states that the image of that set under the functione exists.

Comment: If your version of replacement needs $\varphi$ to be functional everywhere, you can instead define it as "$x$ is a pair in $A$ of the form $(a,y)$,  *or* $x$ is not a pair in $A$ and $x=y$". The second part after the *or* is then just a dummy condition which makes $\varphi$ everywhere functional.

Comment: Ah, I understand.